# Finding BST size C in O(1) time

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I have two questions. What is the current runtime of these two functions? If it's not O(1) (seems like O(n) to me) could someone give me a hint (rather than give me the answer) on how to go about making it into O(1)? Thank you

```
static int size(NODE *r)
{
    if(r==NULL) 
        return 0;

    return size(r->left) + size(r->right) + 1;
}


int bst_size(BST_PTR t)
{
    return size(t->root);
}
```

Comment: You can only make it `O(1)` if you always explicitly store and update the size.

Comment: If you want to find the size of a tree by enumerating all the nodes the it will be Omega(n). Unless you store the size in the nodes as H2CO3 suggests.

Comment: Are the binary search trees [balanced](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree)? Consider [red-black trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree) ...

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry they are size-balanced.. didn't realise the importance of that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nodes could be contained in a BST `struct`, which would have a counter that would be incremented and decremented at insertion/removal.

Comment: This question is about C, which has no classes. If you substitute the word 'class' with 'struct' it could work.

Comment: Yea, the only problem I've come across was at insertion point. I have it recursively so if I were to increment it while it's on the stack it will increment multiple times.

Comment: I thought there would be another way of doing it lol. Nevermind.